# Why does Dynamic for PlotRange in ListLinePlot prevent the proper range from being used?

Tags: plotting, dynamic, manipulate

I am using `Manipulate` to simulate Brownian motion. I want to be able to zoom in. Thus, I want to use `Dynamic` for the `PlotRange` option so that this can be done quickly without recomputing the motion. It works properly without `Dynamic` (except for speed), but using `Dynamic` changes its operation so that the range is no longer what I ask for once I zoom in sufficiently. See this by changing the "horizontal zoom". I also have the same `PlotRange` in Show. It seems I need both. No doubt I am not doing other things optimally, but this issue is a separate problem. Here is my code, first without the first `Dynamic` and second with it. At the end is a smaller example. It behaves differently, but again the behavior depends on whether PlotRange has Dynamic or not. This last example contains both types of code in it. It comes in two forms, one using Show and one not.

```
Manipulate[
Module[{bmPath, iterate}, SeedRandom[seed]; 
iterate[l_List] := 
Module[{i = 1, len = Length[l], new = l}, 
While[i < Length[new], 
 new = Insert[
   new, (new[[i]] + new[[i + 1]])/2 + 
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, .5/Sqrt[(len - 1)]]], 
   i + 1]; i = i + 2]; new]; 
bmPath = {0, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]]}; 
Do[bmPath = iterate[bmPath], {n}]; 
Show[ListLinePlot[bmPath, AxesLabel -> {"Time", "Location"}, 
DataRange -> {0, 1}, 
PlotRange -> {Clip[{hcenter - 2^(-zoom), hcenter + 2^(-zoom)}, {0,
     1}], vcenter + {-2, 2}/2^(scale/2)}], 
Plot[{Sqrt[x], -Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
PlotStyle -> If[bound, Dotted, Opacity[0]]], 
PlotRange -> 
Dynamic[{Clip[{hcenter - 2^(-zoom), hcenter + 2^(-zoom)}, {0, 1}],
   vcenter + {-2, 2}/2^(scale/2)}], 
AxesOrigin -> Dynamic[{hcenter, vcenter}], 
ImageSize -> {475, 360}]],
{{n, 10, "detail"}, 1, 40, 1, Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Open"}, 
AnimationRate -> rate}, {{rate, 1, "rate"}, 1, 3, 1, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{bound, False, 
"show sqrt bounds"}, {True, False}}, Delimiter, {{hcenter, .5, 
"horizontal center"}, 0, 1, .01/2^(zoom - 1), 
Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Open"}, 
AnimationRate -> .2/2^(zoom - 1)}, {{vcenter, 0, 
"vertical center"}, -3, 3, .01/2^(scale - 1), 
Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Open"}, 
AnimationRate -> .1/2^(scale - 1)}, Delimiter, {{zoom, 1, 
"horizontal zoom"}, 1, 20, 1, 
Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Open"}}, {{scale, 1, 
"vertical scale"}, -2, 20, 1, 
Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Open"}}, Delimiter, {{seed, 77777, 
"new random case"}, 10000, 999999, 1, Appearance -> "Open", 
AnimationRate -> newrate}, {{newrate, 1, "rate of new case"}, 1, 10,
1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
ControlPlacement -> Right, SynchronousUpdating -> False]


Manipulate[
Module[{bmPath, iterate}, SeedRandom[seed]; 
iterate[l_List] := 
Module[{i = 1, len = Length[l], new = l}, 
While[i < Length[new], 
 new = Insert[
   new, (new[[i]] + new[[i + 1]])/2 + 
    RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, .5/Sqrt[(len - 1)]]], 
   i + 1]; i = i + 2]; new]; 
bmPath = {0, RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 1]]}; 
Do[bmPath = iterate[bmPath], {n}]; 
Show[ListLinePlot[bmPath, AxesLabel -> {"Time", "Location"}, 
DataRange -> {0, 1}, 
PlotRange -> Dynamic[{Clip[{hcenter - 2^(-zoom), hcenter + 2^(-zoom)}, {0,
     1}], vcenter + {-2, 2}/2^(scale/2)}]], 
Plot[{Sqrt[x], -Sqrt[x]}, {x, 0, 1}, 
PlotStyle -> If[bound, Dotted, Opacity[0]]], 
PlotRange -> 
Dynamic[{Clip[{hcenter - 2^(-zoom), hcenter + 2^(-zoom)}, {0, 1}],
   vcenter + {-2, 2}/2^(scale/2)}], 
AxesOrigin -> Dynamic[{hcenter, vcenter}], 
ImageSize -> {475, 360}]],
{{n, 10, "detail"}, 1, 40, 1, Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Open"}, 
AnimationRate -> rate}, {{rate, 1, "rate"}, 1, 3, 1, 
Appearance -> "Labeled"}, {{bound, False, 
"show sqrt bounds"}, {True, False}}, Delimiter, {{hcenter, .5, 
"horizontal center"}, 0, 1, .01/2^(zoom - 1), 
Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Open"}, 
AnimationRate -> .2/2^(zoom - 1)}, {{vcenter, 0, 
"vertical center"}, -3, 3, .01/2^(scale - 1), 
Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Open"}, 
AnimationRate -> .1/2^(scale - 1)}, Delimiter, {{zoom, 1, 
"horizontal zoom"}, 1, 20, 1, 
Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Open"}}, {{scale, 1, 
"vertical scale"}, -2, 20, 1, 
Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Open"}}, Delimiter, {{seed, 77777, 
"new random case"}, 10000, 999999, 1, Appearance -> "Open", 
AnimationRate -> newrate}, {{newrate, 1, "rate of new case"}, 1, 10,
1, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
ControlPlacement -> Right, SynchronousUpdating -> False]


Manipulate[
Module[{bmPath}, bmPath = {0, 2, 1}; 
Row[{ListLinePlot[bmPath, AxesLabel -> {"Time", "Location"}, 
 DataRange -> {0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> 
  Dynamic[{Clip[{.5 - 2^(-zoom), .5 + 2^(-zoom)}, {0, 1}], {-2, 
     2}}], ImageSize -> {200, 100}], 
ListLinePlot[bmPath, AxesLabel -> {"Time", "Location"}, 
 DataRange -> {0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {Clip[{.5 - 2^(-zoom), .5 + 2^(-zoom)}, {0, 
     1}], {-2, 2}}, ImageSize -> {200, 100}]}]],
{{zoom, 1, "horizontal zoom"}, 1, 20, 1, 
Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Open"}},
ControlPlacement -> Right, SynchronousUpdating -> True]


Manipulate[
Module[{bmPath}, bmPath = {0, 2, 1}; 
Row[{ListLinePlot[bmPath, AxesLabel -> {"Time", "Location"}, 
 DataRange -> {0, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> 
  Dynamic[{Clip[{.5 - 2^(-zoom), .5 + 2^(-zoom)}, {0, 1}], {-2, 
     2}}], ImageSize -> {200, 100}], 
Show[ListLinePlot[bmPath, AxesLabel -> {"Time", "Location"}, 
  DataRange -> {0, 1}], 
 PlotRange -> 
  Dynamic[{Clip[{.5 - 2^(-zoom), .5 + 2^(-zoom)}, {0, 1}], {-2, 
     2}}], ImageSize -> {200, 100}]}]],
{{zoom, 1, "horizontal zoom"}, 1, 20, 1, 
Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Open"}},
ControlPlacement -> Right, SynchronousUpdating -> True]
```

Comment: Is this a *minimum* working example?

Comment: Of course some of the sliders could be eliminated, but they are not very complicated. Because I am not sure what is causing the problem and I need to have all those things there, it is hard to find the minimum example. I have already tried many variations. Sorry about that. However, if you execute this code, I think it will be clear what is going on. I'm happy to clarify anything.

Comment: I just added a minimal example. Sorry for not doing so from the start.

Comment: It's because `Dynamic[{Clip[{.5 - 2^(-zoom), .5 + 2^(-zoom)}, {0, 1}], {-2, 2}}]` is a **not** a proper form for the option `PlotRange`. Further the `Dynamic` wrapper isn't needed.

Comment: Would you mind giving a fuller explanation or pointing to more? As you can see from the first code, Dynamic _is_ needed there when it modifies PlotRange for Show. The whole point of using Dynamic is to speed things up when zooming (or panning, etc.).

Comment: Your first posted example is to big and messy for me to deal with. If your problem is coupled to `Show`, provide a short, simple example that uses `Show`.

Comment: Sorry about that. At the end I added such an example; I hope it provides what you are looking for. BTW, I discovered a slight mathematical error in my original code and edited it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears that `ListLinePlot` needs the `PlotRange` to be an actual list of numbers or another valid setting; something of the form `PlotRange -> Dynamic[expr]` generates an error.  Here's an example:

```
Module[{bmPath}, bmPath = {0, 2, 1};
 Show[
  ListLinePlot[bmPath, AxesLabel -> {"Time", "Location"}, 
   DataRange -> {0, 1}, ImageSize -> {200, 100}, 
   PlotRange -> 
    Dynamic@{Clip[{.5 - 2^(-2), .5 + 2^(-2)}, {0, 1}], {-2, 2}}]
  ]]
```

> ListLinePlot::prng: Value of option PlotRange -> {{0.25,0.75},{-2,2}} is not All, Full, Automatic, a positive machine number, or an appropriate list of range specifications. >>

`ListLinePlot` seems to use `PlotRange` to compute things like the axes, and must have an actual numerical setting or one like `Automatic`.  The way around is to take the graphics returned by `ListLinePlot` and reset the `PlotRange` with `Show`.  `Graphics` may have a dynamic `PlotRange`.  `ListLinePlot` also explicitly sets the `AxesOrigin`, so that needs to be reset to `Automatic` with `Show` as well.

```
Manipulate[
 Module[{bmPath},
  bmPath = Accumulate@RandomReal[{-0.1, 0.1}, 10000];
  Row[{
    Show[
     ListLinePlot[bmPath, AxesLabel -> {"Time", "Location"}, 
      DataRange -> {0, 1}, ImageSize -> {200, 100}],
     PlotRange -> Dynamic@{Clip[{.5 - 2^(-zoom), .5 + 2^(-zoom)}, {0, 1}], Automatic},
     PlotRangePadding -> 0,
     AxesOrigin -> Automatic
     ]}]
  ],
 {{zoom, 1, "horizontal zoom"}, 1, 20, 1, Appearance -> {"Labeled", "Open"}},
 ControlPlacement -> Right, SynchronousUpdating -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: It seems to me that your example does not work: Try increasing the zoom. it is supposed to zoom by a factor of 2 for each increase by 1, but it stops doing that around the value of zoom = 4 and is especially evident around zoom = 8.

Comment: @RussLyons  `PlotRange` is working.  It's `PlotRangePadding` that you're observing.  Set it as you desire.  Above I modified it to be `0`.  `ListLinePlot` does not follow the standard `Plot` option defaults it seems; this may be version dependent.

Comment: @RussLyons You're welcome.

Comment: @MichaelE2, this problem also appears in other array plotting functions (Array/Matrix Plot)- it has been annoying/puzzling me for the past hour. Thanks for clarifying (+1)

Answer (score 3):

[Let me quote something:](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/11191189#11191189)

Kuba said:

> Why some `Options` works with `Dynamic` and other doesn't?

[John Fultz](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/309/john-fultz) said:

> The difference is that some option values get translated directly into `FE` option values. Others affect kernel computation, but don't have a direct translation into the FE.
>
> And, as I've lectured many times before, `Dynamic` is useless unless it's displaying, directly, in the `FE`.
>
> For example, look at the `Plot` function. Something like `ImageSize` goes directly to the `FE`. So `Dynamic` translates well there. But `PlotPoints` affects the underlying mechanisms of `Plot` itself, not anything the `FE` is actually doing.
>
> **If you want to change `PlotPoints` based upon a `Dynamic` setting, then you need to recompute the entire `Plot`**. So `Dynamic` needs to wrap the entire `Plot`.

*`FE` -> `FrontEnd`

Comment: I don't think it will work to wrap the whole plot in Dynamic because then I cannot use SynchronousUpdating -> False, which is the whole point of speeding up the display by not recomputing the data (at least, as far as I understand it).

Comment: @RussLyons This is not the anaswer that says what you have to do but it says why PlotRange with Dynamic is not working. Wrapping everything in Dynamic is quick solution but not necessairly good idea as you can tell. You may ofcourse try specific solutions. P.s. everything in Manipulate body is effectively wrapped in Dynamic.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `PlotRangePadding` of your `ListLinePLot` is absolute and doesn't use `Scaled` expressions.

Compare the behavior of these two examples:

```
center = 2;
width = 2;
llp = ListLinePlot[{1, 2, 3}];
p = Plot[x, {x, 1, 3}];

Manipulate[
 Show[
  llp,
  PlotRange -> Dynamic@{center + width {-1, 1} 2^-zoom, {1, 3}}
  ],
 {zoom, 1, 20, 1}
 ]

Manipulate[
 Show[
  p,
  PlotRange -> Dynamic@{center + width {-1, 1} 2^-zoom, {1, 3}}
  ],
 {zoom, 1, 20, 1}
 ]
```

Like your example, the first fails to zoom any further after a certain point. The second works fine.

Take a look at the option settings for each of those plots:

```
In[90]:= Options[llp, PlotRangePadding]

Out[90]= {PlotRangePadding -> {{0.04, 0.04}, {0.04, 0.04}}}

In[91]:= Options[p, PlotRangePadding]

Out[91]= {PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled[0.02], Scaled[0.02]}}
```

[ref/PlotRangePadding](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/PlotRangePadding.html):

> `PlotRangePadding` is an option for graphics functions that specifies
>   how much further axes etc. should extend beyond the range of
>   coordinates specified by `PlotRange`.

So the behavior here is that your `PlotRangePadding` setting is keeping your range at a minimum of just over .08 coordinate units despite the `PlotRange` setting. You'll want to scale that padding as you zoom, thus `Scaled` is called for.

You might try setting `PlotRangePadding` in the `ListLinePlot` expression itself. For some reason, that doesn't seem to work. In 9.0.1 on Linux, I get back the exact same absolute setting.

It seems like you have to set it with `Show`, side-by-side with `PlotRange`. E.g.:

```
Manipulate[
 Show[
  llp,
  PlotRangePadding -> {Scaled@.02, Scaled@.02},
  PlotRange -> Dynamic@{center + width {-1, 1} 2^-zoom, {1, 3}}
  ],
 {zoom, 1, 20, 1}
 ]
```

I made the same adjustment to your original example. It worked.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation!

Comment: @RussLyons, no problem at all, very glad to help. I don't mean to be overly concerned with rep etc., but what was missing from this answer that made you decide not to mark it as the accepted one? The answer you've currently marked as accepted didn't mention the actual issue at all until an edit and comment about 5 hours ago, which was about 8 hours after I posted this answer.

Comment: It was hard to decide which to accept. I didn't see either of them until this morning, so the order of posting was not a factor. I decided that having 0 padding was what I really wanted, so I accepted that. Actually, while your explanation was very good and helpful, it did not completely answer my question in the sense that it did not explain why Dynamic made a change. Without testing it, I suspect that the reason is that Dynamic prevents the range from being seen at all; having a PlotRange that _is_ seen overrides the default padding. That's why it was so confusing to me in my original code.

Comment: @RussLyons, thanks for this feedback, very fair. Sorry I overlooked that aspect. Even after some more experimentation and lookup right now, I'm not sure why `ListLinePlot` doesn't complain at all about the `Dynamic` wrapper around its `PlotRange` setting. `Plot` certainly complains in the same setting. E.g. `Manipulate[Plot[x, {x, 1, 3}, PlotRange -> Dynamic@s], {s, 1, 20}]` vs. `Manipulate[ListLinePlot[Range@3, PlotRange -> Dynamic@s], {s, 1, 20}]`. I filed a report with WRI in case it's bad behavior. Anyway, thanks for your kind and thoughtful words.

Comment: BTW, at some point when I have more time, it is possible I will decide that in the end, I will want scaled padding as you suggested. But for now I use 0.

Comment: WRI Support confirms that the silence of `ListLinePlot` re `PlotRange -> Dynamic` is unintended and is now fixed for the next version.

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for doing that.